# Check if logged in user via SSH did go through Active Direcory

Tags: sshd, pam

I'm trying to check if a user who connects to a linux server via SSH is authentificated using Active Directory (Centrify).

In case he uses a local account (located in `/etc/passwd`), I need to display a warning asking him to use his Active Directory account and then prompt login again.

My first attempt was using PAM module pam_script inside `/etc/pam.d/login` to execute a script that checks if the current username exists in /etc/passwd whenever a user log in, display a warning if found and call the `login` command again.

I added the following line to `/etc/pam.d/login`

```
session    required    pam_script.so runas=root
```

This line execute a script file located in `/etc/security/onsessionopen` which contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
username=$1

if [ $(grep -c '^'$username':' /etc/passwd) = 1 ] 
then
    echo "Warning, please user your AD credentials"
    login
fi
```

But the same scenario didn't work in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.
When using SSH the script does run but doesn't display text or prompt for login.

Any thoughts ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using `id` it is relatively easy to know if you are connected from ad or local `/etc/passwd`. next step would be to have a function in `/etc/profile` that will issue the warning message.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, I did your suggestion, but I'm wondering how to re-invoke the login step inside /etc/profile after displaying the warning.

Comment: @WinkoBit don't try to reinvoke login. It's far easier to throw the user out and let them try again.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome solution for standard 'login'. Unfortunately, I don't think you'll have much luck getting this same behavior going for 'sshd'. This is due to the fundamental connection procedures which sshd utilizes when establishing a connection. By the time we get so far as the PAM stack (or profile bits, as in the other suggestion), the username is already resolved; as submitted by the SSH client.

Here's a resource that may shed more light on this: https://serverfault.com/questions/330310/force-ssh-to-prompt-for-user

Given this info, I would suggest that an ideal solution may be to stick with your script (or /etc/profile addition), however for the 'sshd' stack; rather than hit 'login', have it sleep for 10s or what-have-you (to ensure the warning is seen), and then have the session closed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the shell for relevant accounts in `/etc/passwd` would work well

Put this into (say) `/usr/local/etc/mustuseadlogin` and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "Please log in with AD authentication" >&2
echo
sleep 10
exit 0
```

Now edit `/etc/passwd` (ideally with `vipw`) and change the last field for all affected accounts to be `/usr/local/etc/mustuseadlogin`. For example,

```
roaima:x:1001:1001:I am roaima:/home/roaima:/usr/local/etc/mustuseadlogin
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pam_script` module uses its exit status to tell the calling stack what to do. Change your code to this, and it'll work:

```
#!/bin/bash
username="$1"

if [[ root != "$username" ]] && grep -q '^'"$username"':' /etc/passwd
then
    echo "Warning, please user your AD credentials"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

I've excluded `root` from the block. You can adjust the `[[ ... ]]` test for UIDs < 500, etc., to apply to your own scenario.

Comment: make sure root can connect.

Comment: @Archemar thank you for that suggestion. Code updated (I do prefer my [other answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295938/100397), though.)